# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException when running jar file

Tags: java, jar, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a jar file that I would like to run. I originally was running it in a batch script but now I want to run it as a shell script. (I did not write this code so I do not have access to the main class)

My jar file is called MyFile.jar and I am using

```
java -jar MyFile.jar
```

However, I get an error saying:

```
ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

This is the only error I get.

In the batch script, the file is executed using

```
java -cp MyFile.jar com.mycomapnny.example.Main "path of where to put output"
```

I think it has something to do with needing arguments. But I am not sure what arguments to pass in since I can't look at the main class.

Any help would be appreciated. I can try to provide any additional information I can.

Comment: Inspect the original batch and call it the same wasly or decompile the jar If you have doubts. What happens when you use . as the First parameter ?

Comment: Well, first try to find out what kind of arguments the program needs (website / contact developer). If that doesn't work, you could put it in a java decompiler (might be illegal depending on the program's license though) and look at the `main` function in the Main-Class: http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: @Marged When I put . as the first parameter, I got  java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./config.properties (no such file or directory).  I do have that file for the batch script so maybe I just need to had that to my new script?

Comment: You can have the same script content and directory structure between Windows and Unix. Only difference that matters: use / instead of \